# Difference between two dates returns date instead of number [DAX]

Tags: powerpivot, dax, powerbi

In PowerPivot DAX formulas, I need the number of days between two dates.

My formula is

```
ProjectDays:=[ProjectFinish]-[ProjectStart]
```

But instead of a number, it returns a date.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ProjectDays:= VALUE( [ProjectFinish] - [ProjectStart] )

VALUE() is the poorly named 'convert to numeric type' function.